# How to find a string of text, but exclude text from a text file?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

How to exclude a line of text with “K-Address”, when there is a line of text with “Address”?

I want the line of text with the word "Address", but then I don't want the line of text if it has "K-Address" (for example).  I have this code below but it grabs both lines with Address and K-Address, so I have 2 lines.  I just want the one line with "Address".  How can I make this happen?

```
myRDD.filter(line => line.contains("Address") && !(line.contains("K-Address")) )
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48390225/edit) the post to include a sample of the input data, the expected output, and the actual output? If there's an issue it's hiding somewhere in those details...

Comment: Cyrillic `К`? :)

Comment: I found the problem elsewhere in my code, so what I had posted in my question is correct. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`myRDD.filter(line => line.contains(“Address”) && !(line.contains("K-Address")) )`

This is correct to exclude and include text in the same line.

Comment: Steve, could you point where the problem was so this answer could be useful for someone else?

Comment: The code that I supplied in the original answer was correct.  I had issues elsewhere in my code, but what I had was correct.